# Getting VLC media player to play to the end of an MP4

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player

How can I get VLC media player to play to the end of an MP4?

Here (V3.0.8, Windows 7), the playback stops one second short of the end of every .mp4 file tried [image]e.g.

The same videos play fine on YouTube e.g. https://youtu.be/yUSizQBWfW0

[image: https://i.imgur.com/8Kqdsy5.png]

Unsurprisingly the player fails to loop regardless of the loop/repeat button - on loop all or loop one https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Tli.png.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a link to the .mp4 file?

Comment: Never mind. Downloaded it. I cannot reproduce with the same setup as you have.